# How can I use xdebug with wp-cli

Tags: wp-cli, debug

I'd like to use xdebug and vscode to debug a script I'm running via `wp eval-file`.

My launch.json is pretty basic.

```
    {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
    }
```

my php.ini has xdebug config, and debugging a simple stand-alone php script works.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
```

I am not sure what I could be missing

---

EDIT
This is the php.ini config that ended up working

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

This is the command

```bash
wp eval-file test-debug.php --use-include --skip-wordpress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since wp-cli version 2.8.0 the `--use-include` flag makes **XDebug** work with `wp eval-file` as it will use `include()` for  the file instead of using `eval()`.

See more here:

https://make.wordpress.org/cli/2023/05/31/wp-cli-v2-8-0-release-notes/

https://github.com/wp-cli/eval-command/issues/49

Comment: This is perfect. So excited to try this! I had HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 in my .zshrc, and it was preventing updates to latest versions of all the things... did that a while back when packages for Ventura will still sketchy...

Comment: this didn't end up working. https://xdebug.org/wizard shows php 8.2 has xdebug 3.2.2 installed and working, but I'm not getting breakpoints....

Comment: I got this working by adding `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`. I would have never gotten it working without the `--use-include` flag and updating to wp-cli 2.8.0. Many thanks!

Comment: great, thanks for sharing that info @JJS